# How to start a virtual machine on a Mac where I am not a root/admin?

Tags: mac, virtualization, user-accounts

I want to have my own little unpolluted environment where I can test a project I am working on. The physical computer is a university Mac, and I don't want to interfere with its environment, so I thought a virtual machine is a clean way to work at this computer.

The problem is that I don't have admin account on this computer, and so I cannot perform any installations that alter the system-wide environment, such as VirtualBox, for instance.

Is there any way I can install some form of virtual machine manager and start a virtual machine on this Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Links), and better yet, the [Q.app](http://www.kju-app.org/).

However, performance and reliability are way worse than with Virtual Box, Parallels or Fusion. It might work for your situation, though.